# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException in clojure file encryption program

Tags: java, encryption, file-io, clojure, aes

First, let me say I am very new to clojure, and has been some time since I did a great deal with java or the jvm too.

I am getting a javax.crypto.BadPaddingException when I try to decrypt a file that was encrypted by the same program.  Following is the code:

```
(ns clojure-crypt-file.core
(:use [clojure.tools.cli :only [cli]])
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
      [me.raynes.fs :as fs])
(:import (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64)
     (javax.crypto Cipher KeyGenerator SecretKey)
     (javax.crypto.spec SecretKeySpec)
     (java.security SecureRandom))
(:gen-class))

(defn str-to-bytes [s] (.getBytes s "UTF-8"))
(defn bytes-to-str [bs] (apply str (map (comp char byte) bs)))

(defn base64 [b]
  (Base64/encodeBase64String b))

(defn debase64 [s]
  (Base64/decodeBase64 (str-to-bytes s)))

(defn fetch-b64-key [filename]
(let [encoded-key (slurp filename)
     size (count encoded-key)
     ekey-no-newline (apply str (take (dec size) encoded-key))]
     (bytes-to-str (debase64 ekey-no-newline))))

(defn get-raw-key [seed]
  (let [keygen (KeyGenerator/getInstance "AES")
    sr (SecureRandom/getInstance "SHA1PRNG")]
    (.setSeed sr (str-to-bytes seed))
    (.init keygen (count seed) sr)
    (.. keygen generateKey getEncoded)))

(defn get-cipher [mode seed]
  (let [key-spec (SecretKeySpec. (get-raw-key seed) "AES")
    cipher (Cipher/getInstance "AES")]
    (.init cipher mode key-spec) cipher))

(defn encrypt [ba key]
  (let [cipher (get-cipher Cipher/ENCRYPT_MODE key)]
    (.doFinal cipher ba)))


(defn decrypt [enc-buffer key]
  (let [cipher (get-cipher Cipher/DECRYPT_MODE key)]
  (str-to-bytes (String. (.doFinal cipher enc-buffer)))))


(defn encrypt-file [src-file dest-file key-text]
  (let  [in     (new java.io.FileInputStream src-file)
     out    (java.io.BufferedOutputStream. 
             (java.io.FileOutputStream. dest-file))
     buffer (make-array Byte/TYPE 16)
     encbuf (atom nil)]
    (loop [g (.read in buffer) r 0]
  (if-not (= g -1)
    (do
      (reset! encbuf (encrypt buffer key-text));(println r "/" size)
      (.write out (deref encbuf) 0 (count (deref encbuf)))
      (recur (.read in buffer) (+ r g)))))
(.close in)
(.close out)) nil)

(defn decrypt-file [src-file dest-file key-text]
  (let  [in     (new java.io.FileInputStream src-file)
     out    (java.io.BufferedOutputStream. 
             (java.io.FileOutputStream. dest-file))
     buffer (make-array Byte/TYPE 16)
     decbuf (atom nil)]
  (loop [g (.read in buffer) r 0]
    (if-not (= g -1)
      (do
        (reset! decbuf (decrypt buffer key-text));(println r "/" size)
        (.write out (deref decbuf) 0 (count (deref decbuf)))
        (recur (.read in buffer) (+ r g)))))
  (.close in)
  (.close out)) nil)

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  ;; work around dangerous default behaviour in Clojure
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))

 (def ret-val
      (let [[opts extra banner] 
      (cli args
          ["-e" "--encrypt" "Encrypt source file" :flag true :default false]
          ["-d" "--decrypt" "Decrypt source file" :flag true :default false] 
          ["-k" "--keyfile" "Path to keyfile" :default "./keyfile"]
          ["-h" "--help" "Help" :flag true :default false] 
          )]

    ;(println opts extra)
    (if (true? (:help opts)) banner
        (let [
            sfile (first extra) 
            dfile (if (= (count extra) 2) 
              (second extra)
              (if (true? (:encrypt opts))
                  (str (first extra) ".encrypted")
                  (str (first extra) ".decrypted"))) 
            ktext (slurp (:keyfile opts))
              ]

              (if (true? (:encrypt opts)) (encrypt-file sfile dfile ktext)
                                  (decrypt-file sfile dfile ktext))))))

(if (nil? ret-val) (println "Finished.") (println ret-val)))
```

Following is the complete error listing:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:317)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1813)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
  at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
  at clojure_crypt_file.core$decrypt.invoke(core.clj:54)
  at clojure_crypt_file.core$decrypt_file.invoke(core.clj:83)
  at clojure_crypt_file.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:117)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
  at clojure_crypt_file.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

From a previous post, concerning an actual java program, it was suggested that this maybe a problem with the last few bytes of data not filling the buffer.  I'm not sure if that's exactly true here or not.  No matter what the cause is, I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just thought I would add that the above exception is generated at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: I have working code for this now, I will try to get around to posting it sometime.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main causes of a BadPaddingException:

1. You are encrypting/decrypting incorrectly so what should be the padding is coming out as random garbage.
2. You are adding one sort of padding (or none) at encryption and expecting a different sort of padding on decryption so the two don't match.

The way to check is to temporarily set your decryption method to expect `NoPadding`.  That setting won't throw the error, and so allows the program to proceed.  **Only** do this for debugging.  That will allow you to see what the decrypted message looks like.

If the whole message is random rubbish then you are either encrypting or decrypting incorrectly. Check key, IV mode etc. are the same for both encryption and decryption at the byte level.

If the message is clear, but there are some bytes added to the end, then those extra bytes are the padding.  Check against the various padding types and set your decryption method to expect that type of padding.  Alternatively set both encryption and decryption methods to use PKCS7 padding.

If there is no padding visible, just the message, then you should add a full block of padding -- sixteen bytes for AES -- before encryption.  That may mean altering the settings on your encryption method.

I'm afraid I don't know clojure, so you will have to look up the details of how to do this in the manual.

Comment: I have just completed a thorough test of the the encrypt and decrypt functions using (randomly generated) strings small enough to fit into memory (up to 18 Mb).  All tests succeeded.  I am sure that I am not encrypting/decrypting correctly with respect to the file I/O.  My problem is that I am not certain how to read a chunk from a file, transform that chunk (in this case encrypt/decrypt), then write transformed chunk to another file, repeating these steps until the end of the source file is reached.

Comment: Set up a small text file as a test and try encrypting/decrypting that from disk.  In Java the way to deal with unknown length data is to use streams.  I am not sure if clojure allows access to Java streams.